# How to print regression equation from coefficients matrix?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a regression coefficients matrix. The independent variables are `x, x^2, x^3`, till `x^N` where `N` is a parameter of my choice. I would like to print a line saying the following.

"The regression model is: `y= a1 x+ a2 x^2+ a3 x^3 + ... + x^N`"

The numbers from the coefficients matrix must be printed in place of `a1`, `a2`, etc. The code should work for different `N` equally well.

Comment: you should have shared, what you have done so far, so that it would be easy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through your list of coefficients and build a list of strings with the textual representation of each term, then join them with '+' to create the equation.

```
def f(coefficients):
  def term(coef, power):
    coef = coef if coef != 1 else ''
    power = (f'^{power}') if power > 1 else ''
    return f'{coef}x{power}'
  terms = []
  for power, coef in enumerate(coefficients, start=1):
    if coef != 0:
      terms.append(term(coef, power))
  return 'y = ' + ' + '.join(terms)

equation = f([8, 7, 0, -9, 1])
print(equation) # prints 'y = 8x + 7x^2 + -9x^4 + x^5'
```